# How do I make the hint text available for screenreaders?

Tags: orbeon

When I add a hint text to a text field in the [form builder demo](https://demo.orbeon.com/demo/fr/orbeon/builder/new), I noticed that this hint text is not linked to the input through an aria-describedby attribute when I test the form.

Is this a bug, or does the author or user of the form need to do something to generate this attribute?

Comment: The `label` has a `for` attribute pointing to the `<input>` (say, if you have a text field). In addition to the label, there are 2 other elements with information about the input: the hint (inside a `<span class="xforms-hint">`) and the help (inside a `<span class="xforms-help">`). Those 2 are not semantically linked to the `<input>`. We could imagine generating an id on those 2 elements, and on the `<input>` add an attribute `aria-describedby="hint-id help-id"` (with the actual ids we have on the hint and help).

Comment: This would seem more "semantically correct", but in practice does it really help screen readers? Is this something you've tried? I'm asking, because this would make the markup heavier, adding an id and reference to that id for every control for every hint and every help, a price we wouldn't want to pay if it doesn't help screen readers.